# std::vector::operator[] doesn't test type

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion

I have a struct like this:

```
struct VrtxPros{
    long idx;
    std::vector<std::string> pros;
    VrtxPros(const long& _idx=-1, const std::string& val="") : idx(_idx)
    {
         if ( !val.empty() && val!="" )
             pros.push_back(val);
    }
};
```

and later in the code I use it like that:

```
long idx = 1234;
VrtxPros vp( 2134, std::string("-1") );
if ( margin ) vp.pros[0] = idx;
```

The compiler has no problem with that. I am wondering because the operator should deliver a reference.
I [could not find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator=) an `operator=` in `std::string` which would accept a long as source.

Why does the code compile?

Comment: `basic_string& operator=( CharT ch ); 4) Replaces the contents with character ch`. Your `long` is probably being converted to a character. Other things to note are that your `!= ""` check is redundant if I didn't miss something, and that passing `"-1"` is fine because `std::string` has an implicit conversion constructor for `const char *`.

Comment: @mistapink, A long is implicitly convertible to a `char`. http://ideone.com/wNd4u

Comment: @mistapink, As for `CharT`, it's the first template argument to `std::basic_string<>`, which is `char` for `std::string`. To compare, `CharT` would be `wchar_t` for `std::wstring`.

Comment: g++ implicitly casts int to char..

Comment: @Hrishi, g++ shouldn't be the only one: `int x = 999; ...; char c1 = x; // OK, though it might narrow (in this case, it does narrow)` Taken from the C++11 standard, § 8.5.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `std::string` can be assigned to a `char`, and a `long` can be implicitly converted to a `char`, so a `std::string` can be assigned to a `long`. Your compiler will probably give a warning about this kind of implicit conversion (turn up the warning level and you'll see it, if you don't already).

See the #4 `operator=` listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D). Notice no [constructor overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) takes just a char, so this sort of thing can only be done for assignment.

For that matter, you can do this too:

```
std::string wow;
wow = 7ull; // implicit unsigned long long to char conversion
wow = 1.3f; // implicit float to char conversion
```

Comment: I get no warnings from my linked sample. It's only `operator=` that does this, not a constructor, so it's pretty deliberate most of the time.

Comment: @chris in VS2010 with warning level 4 I get a warning from your code and mine.

Comment: @chris: Yes, it is deliverate in the standard, and no, I don't really understand why, but there is an overload of `operator=` in `std::basic_string<>` that takes a single `CharT` object. Why would you want such an operation is something I have wondered in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Use -Wconversion for g++ to get a warning for the implicit conversion from long to char.

Comment: Ah, surprised I never had that one included.